# regular expression for log file

Tags: regex, vbscript, vb6

I have log file like this:

```
<CL>
text sample1
<CL>
<CL>
<TR></TR>
</CL>
<CL>
<CL>
<CL>
<TR1></TR1>
</CL>
<CL>
text sample2
<CL>
text sample3
<CL>
<TR1>
<TR2></TR2>
</TR1>
</CL>
```

I need to write regular expression which returns 
valid xml from this file. I need this result:

```
<CL>
<TR></TR>
</CL>

<CL>
<TR1></TR1>
</CL>

<CL>
<TR1>
<TR2></TR2>
</TR1>
</CL>
```

This variand doesn't work for me:

```
<CL>[\s\S]*?(<CL>[\s\S]+?</CL>)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: < and > should be escaped normally.

Comment: Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work for your example

```
"<CL>((?!<CL>).)*?(?:<TR[\\d]*?>)+.*?(?:</TR[\\d]*?>)+.*?</CL>"
```

Note, that dependend of programming language, you should set the `Singleline` regex option in order this regex to work

**EDIT** in some languages there is no need to escape \d, so try also

```
"<CL>((?!<CL>).)*?(?:<TR[\d]*?>)+.*?(?:</TR[\d]*?>)+.*?</CL>"
```

**EDIT2** If you just want to catch the cl tag content, you can simply use:

```
<CL>((?!<CL>).)*</CL>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? Aren't you for example escaping the \d by writing \\d?

Comment: @Vaelor I've checked it in C# as at the moment I've answered, OP didn't provide us with any info about programming language. So in c# slashes must be escaped this way. In some other languages not, but thanks for advice

Comment: @VladL thanks for reply. I have checked it on vbscript language and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Iurii I can imagine that, I've just found this article http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html and vbscript regex differs from posix

Comment: @Vlad_L may I ask you additional question? May be you have any idea how to write it without assign to tag <TR> 
because sometimes logs could contain different tag but I know exactly that it contain tags <CL> </CL>

Comment: @VladL thank you for help. I've checked it on site http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?3417s and it workes with dotall flag but vbscript doesn't support this flag. On one site I've read that in vbscript we can use characters [\s\S], so I'll try to modify your expression. Thank you)

Answer (score 2):

As i experienced, the regular expressions is not so good for XML file validation, parsing, and reading.

Better to use a DOM PARSER solution for this problem. Most of them have validation method. 
In php: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php (a lot work with this)

Or PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ (just read the xml file and print the object created from xml, and get the valid xml struct, as i remember it works not only for HTML struct)
In java: JSOUP library http://jsoup.org/ (nearly same as simpledom in php)

And first at all, a valid xml file should contains a root tag 
(Like HTML tag in html files , this wrapping the document )

I hope this helps you out